# Custom Resource name Android

Tags: android, resources

I could not find an answer to this question anywhere so I have posted it.

Let's say I have multiple resource strings, like:

```
<string name="hello">Hello World, MainScreen!</string>
<string name="app_name">My Title</string>
```

And I reference them in my code like so:

```
R.values.hello
R.values.app_name
```

But how can I access them like this?

```
String test = "hello";
String value = R.values.test;
```

I am trying to do something like this, but on a much larger scale.  Or is there a different, but better way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

In an Activity, this will work...

```
String value = getString(R.values.hello);
```

R.values.hello is an integer used as a 'lookup' for the actual string itself. All resources are handled this way.

Comment: I mistyped my question and just fixed it.  I meant trying to do:  String test = "hello";
String value = R.values.test;

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to obtain those values would be

> String name =
>   CurrentClassName.this.getString(R.string.hello);

By using CurrentClassName.this you will assure that you can use it inside functions and nested classes.

Comment: I mistyped my question and just fixed it.  I meant trying to do:  String test = "hello";
String value = R.values.test;

Comment: I'm not following what you mean

Comment: I'm trying to basically make it be dynamic.  So like let's say I have two buttons.  The user press button #1 then it gets the R.values.hello.  But if the user presses button #2 then it gets the R.values.app_name.  However, I am going to have a LOT of buttons...so I do not want to have nested if statements.

Answer (score 1):

I think this link might help you http://steven.bitsetters.com/2007/11/27/accessing-android-resources-by-name-at-runtime/

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("hello", "values", getPackageName());
```